# Qual a utilidade do Func<T, TResult>

Tags: c#, .net

Estava pesquisando algumas coisas e me deparei com o `Func<T, TResult>`, e não entendi muito bem a utilidade dele.

Por exemplo:

```
//Método
public string Nome(string nome)
{
    return "Meu nome é " + nome
}

//Ao utiliza-lo eu chamaria assim
string nome = Nome("Josias");
```

E utilizando o `Func<T, TResult>`:

```
Func<string, string> metodo = Nome;

string nome = metodo("Josias");
```

Não consegui perceber nenhuma diferença em usar o `Func<T, TResult>`.

Em que casos seria útil utilizar o `Func<T, TResult>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Qual a utilidade

Passar para um método (ou uma função) uma outra função. [É um tipo de `delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/900fyy8e.aspx).

## Como ler `Func<T, TResult>`

> Função com um argumento do tipo **T** que devolve um valor do tipo **TResult**.

## Não consegui perceber nenhuma diferença em usar o `Func<T, TResult>`.

Na verdade você não passou função alguma para uma variável usada em outra função. Apenas chamou a variável com o argumento. Por isso a utilidade não é bem percebida.

## Em que casos seria útil utilizar o `Func<T, TResult>`?

[A resposta do dcastro tem um bom exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68827/2999). Vou colocar outro baseado no dele:

```
IEnumerable<int> AplicarOperacaoMatematicaEmLista(IEnumerable<int> lista, Func<int, int> funcao)
{
    foreach (var item in lista)
        yield return funcao(item);
}
```

Uso:

```
var potenciaDeDois = delegate(int numero) { return numero * numero; };
var listaDeInteiros = new List<int> { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
var listaDeQuadrados = AplicarOperacaoMatematicaEmLista(listaDeInteiros, potenciaDeDois);
// Vai imprimir uma lista com { 4, 16, 36, 64, 100 }
```

Answer (score 8):

Imagina que estas a escrever um metodo que transforma cada elemento duma lista num outro elemento. Queres que esta transformacao seja arbitraria, e definida pelo utilizador. Isto seria implementado assim:

```
IEnumerable<TResult> Map<T, TResult>(IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, TResult> transform)
{
    foreach(var item in collection)
        yield return transform(item);
}
```

Assim, o utilizador poderá passar como argumento qualquer função que receba um dos elementos da lista (de tipo `T`) como argumento e que o transforme num outro elemento (de tipo `TResult`).

```
var list = new List<int> {1,2,3};
var doubled = Map(list, item => item * 2);
```

Moral da história: `Func<T, TResult>` (e qualquer outro delegate em geral) serve para passares funções arbitrárias. Serve para poderes tratar funções como objectos/valores (este é o pilar do paradigma FP - functional programming).

Este método que usei como exemplo (`Map`) é na verdade idêntico à extensão [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Aliás, as extensões LINQ dependem fortemente na passagem de delegates como argumentos (`Where`, `Any`, `All`, `GroupBy`, `OrderBy`, `SelectMany`, `SkipWhile`, etc).

Comment: É bom deixar claro também que `Func<>` assim como os outros `delegate`s genéricos disponibilizados na .NET servem como conveniência para facilitar a vida do programador. Não precisariam existir, mas são atalhos de programação genérica para não precisar declarar um `delegate` novo toda vez que um for necessário. Ou seja, é parte da utilidade do mesmo simplificar a declaração de um tipo de `delegate`s.

Answer (score 1):

Func é um delegate (um "ponteiro" para uma função).

Neste caso, qualquer método que receba uma string como parâmetro e retorno uma string poderá ser utilizado.

aproveite para estudar Action e Predicate também:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317479/func-vs-action-vs-predicate

Comment: A pergunta não é "o que é o `Func<T,TResult>`?", mas sim "Qual a sua  utilidade?"