# Como implementar uma função para retornar a soma dos quadrados da forma proposta?

Tags: c#

não entendi bem o proposto aqui. A dúvida toda está no combiner, pelo enunciado, entendo ser um delegate. Veja, não precisam postar códigos, gostaria de apenas um caminho a seguir. Abaixo o enunciado. Toda a parte marcada com a tag code, é o enunciado, inclusive os textos. Fazer uma função que retorne a soma dos quadrados eu já fiz e está funcionando, mas preciso agora da forma proposta por esse exercício.

```
function acumular(combiner, nullValue, list)
{
    if (list.length == 0) {
        return nullValue;
    }
    var primeiro = list.removePrimeiro();
    return combiner(primeiro, acumular (combiner, nullValue, list));
}

Implemente a função somaDeQuadrados que retorna a soma de quadrados de uma lista.

somaDeQuadrados([1,2,3,4,5])
retorna o número 55.

Neste caso a função acumular deve ser utilizada. A variável “combiner” é um “ponteiro para função”. A implementação da função “combiner” faz parte da solução.
```

O que preciso mesmo é de um caminho e não de código, pois quero fazer, como já fiz os demais.

Minha grande dúvida está na implementação de Combine. Não entendi de forma integral o que o dcastro postou. Se alguém entendeu ou o próprio dcastro, puder, agradeço com qualquer ajuda adicional.

A minha maior dificuldade está na implementação da função Acumular, pois ela recebe um argumento do tipo de um método(Combiner). Meu método Combiner está assim implementado:

```
private int Combiner(int primeiro, int acc)
        {
            acc += primeiro * primeiro;

            return acc;
        }
```

E o método acumular estou apanhando assim:

```
public int acumular(int combiner, int? nullValue, List<int> list)
        {            
            if (list.Count == 0)
                return 0;
            var primeiro = list.First();
            list.RemoveAt(0);

            return Combiner(primeiro, acumular(Combiner(primeiro,1),null,list));
        }
```

O return 0 está fora do proposto e os parâmetros na chamada recursiva de acumular.

Achei que estivesse errada, mas deu certo a soma dos quadrados da forma acima. Fiz a chamada assim:

```
int[] inteiros = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
List<int> lista = new List<int>(inteiros);
lblFat.Text = f.acumular(1,null,lista).ToString();
```

Como já havia o array, eu apenas atribui o array à lista, para não ficar preenchendo, por isso tem array e lista na chamada, mas a chamada não vai para o teste.

Comment: Isto não está exatamente em C#, não? Acho que seria legal editar a pergunta e deixar tudo em C#. Não vejo problema de responder objetivamente, com código. [Veja também se esta resposta te ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68760/qual-a-utilidade-do-funct-tresult/68833#68833).

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, a questão está exatamente aí, passar para o C#.

Comment: @pnet Actualizei a minha resposta com correcções ao teu código actual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`acumular` é uma função que percorre uma lista, da esquerda para a direita, e que vai chamando a função `combine` passando 2 argumentos:

1. O valor que está actualmente a ser examinado
2. O acumulador do resto da lista

Portanto, `combiner` deve ter a seguinte assinatura:

```
int combine(int x, int acc)
```

No final, ela vai ser chamada assim:

```
combine(1, combine(2, combine(3, combine(4, combine(5, nullValue)))))
```

Acho que estas dicas deverão ser suficientes para resolveres o exercício.

(Nota: esta função `acumular` é geralmente chamada de `foldRight` / `fold` em linguagens de programação funcional, ou [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.100).aspx) no caso específico de C#)

---

**Update**

Algumas coisas de errado com o teu codigo actual:

1. o parâmetro `combiner` da função `acumular` deve ser um apontador para uma função (como diz no enunciado), e não um `int`. Entao devia ser do tipo `Func<int, int, int>` - ou seja, `combiner` é um delegate que aceita dois inteiros e retorna outro inteiro.
2. `nullValue` e' do tipo `int`, nao `int?`
3. O valor de `nullValue` não é `null` - acho que o nome do parâmetro foi mal escolhido. O valor de `nullValue` é o inteiro que vai ser *combinado* com o 5 logo no início. Qual inteiro achas que deveria ser?
4. A última linha da função `acumular` está errada: não podes chamar a função `Combiner`, apenas o delegate `combiner`.
5. Na verdade, a última linha da função `acumular` pode ser copiada do enunciado sem alterações: `return combiner(primeiro, acumular (combiner, nullValue, list))`

Se ainda tiveres dúvidas, posso colocar aqui a resposta integral, mas acho que consegues chegar lá só com estas dicas ;)

---

**Solução**

```
public int Acumular(Func<int, int, int> combiner, int nullValue, List<int> list)
{            
    if (list.Count == 0)
        return 0;

    var primeiro = list.First();
    list.RemoveAt(0);

    return combiner(primeiro, Acumular(combiner, nullValue, list));
}

public int Combiner(int x, int acumulador)
{
    return (x*x) + acumulador;    
}

var list = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};

Acumular(Combiner, 0, list);
```

Como `combiner` vai ser chamado recursivamente, então vai ser chamado assim:

```
combiner(1, combiner(2, combiner(3, combiner(4, combiner(5, nullValue)))))
```

Substituindo `combiner` pela fórmula `x*x + acumulador`, e `nullValue` por 0:

```
1*1 + (2*2 + (3*3 + (4*4 + (5*5 + 0))))
```

O que é igual a 55

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ljkCu5

Comment: não entedi a forma como você colocou a chamada a combine.

Comment: @pnet pensa na notação duma fórmula matematica, ex: `1 + (2 + (3 + (5 + x)))`. Ou seja, primeiro vai ser chamado `combine(5, nullValue)`. O resultado dessa chamada, vai ser passado para outra chamada `combine(4, resultadoAnterior)`, e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: @pnet Sim, é isso. Tenta imaginar como seria a execucao da funcao `acumular` se passares como argumento a lista `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Tenta escrever num papel, e vai mantendo registo da call stack. Repara que a funcao `acumular` é recursiva - no final, ela vai chamar `combine(5, nullValue)`, e vai retornar o resultado. Depois, esse resultado vai ser *combinado* com 4, depois com o 3, etc etc.

Comment: Show, dcastro. Agora acho que eu entendi o que fazer. Vou começar a fazer. Hoje é meu último dia para entregar e só falta dois métodos para terminar. Os demais já fiz.

Comment: @pnet coloquei a solução

Comment: Deu certo, dcastro, na mosca. Obrigado de verdade.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar também uma [função em linha](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    List<int> list = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Usando a lista proposta:

```
    Func<List<int>, int> Qd = null;
    Qd = 
        x => 
        (x.Count == 0) ? 0 : x.Last() * x.Last() + Qd(x.Take(x.Count-1).ToList<int>());


    var resultado = Qd(list);
```

Ainda usando Linq

```
    Func<List<int>, int> Qd = 
        x => 
        x.Select(i => i*i).Sum();
    var resultado = Qd(list);
```

Usando a passagem de função, como proposto pelo enunciado

```
    Func<Func<int, int, int>, List<int>, int> Qd = null;
    Qd = 
        (a, c) => 
        (c.Count == 0) ? 0 : a(c.Last(), Qd(a, c.Take(c.Count-1).ToList<int>()));
    Func<int, int, int> QdS = 
        (a, b) => 
        b + (a*a);

    //neste caso a chamada deve ser feita assim:
    var resultado = Qd(QdS, list);
```

Os dois exemplos estão no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b14sog)

Comment: Po, desse jeito também funcionou. São muitos os caminhos a serem seguidos, rs.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. O objecto do exercício era usar a abordagem funcional `fold`. Como o @pnet disse, "Fazer uma função que retorne a soma dos quadrados eu já fiz e está funcionando, mas preciso agora da forma proposta por esse exercício."

Comment: Agora deve responder ao enunciado. Obrigado.