# Quando e onde usar um delegate no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, delegate

Sou novo em C# e ainda não entendi totalmente o conceito da utilização de um `delegate`:

```
public delegate void HTTPRequestsHandler(string url);
```

Gostaria de saber quando usá-los e em quais casos um `delegate` é útil.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Sua pergunta é muito parecida com esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68760/qual-a-utilidade-do-funct-tresult/68833#68833), mas o contexto é um pouco diferente.

*Delegates* podem ser definidos, grosso modo, a tipos que definem funções. No seu exemplo:

```
public delegate void HTTPRequestsHandler(string url);
```

Você está definindo o tipo `HTTPRequestsHandler`, que é um tipo de função que não devolve nada, e cujo argumento é uma `string`.

O principal uso de *delegates* é o de definir funções em tempo de execução. Neste exemplo, a ideia deve ser definir uma função que trate requisições HTTP já com o aplicativo executando.

Suponha que você escreve um servidor que receba requisições HTTP, mas quer dar a liberdade de outras pessoas escreverem exatamente como querem que a requisição seja processada. Seu servidor irá esperar uma função em tempo de execução, e seu código apenas se concentrará em chamar esta função no tempo adequado.

## Exemplos

### Sem *delegate*

Suponha uma classe assim:

```
public class MeuServidor
{
    public void MinhaFuncaoQueTrataHttpRequests(string url) 
    {
        /* Note que aqui preciso declarar minha função. 
           Não tenho a opção de declarar ela em outro momento. */
    }
}
```

### Com *delegate*

Suponha a declaração tanto do *delegate* quanto da minha classe assim:

```
public delegate void HTTPRequestsHandler(string url);

public class MeuServidor
{
    public HTTPRequestsHandler minhaFuncaoDelegate { get; set; }
}
```

Note que ela aparece como propriedade, e que eu posso usar o `set` para defini-la em outro ponto do código. Assim:

```
HTTPRequestsHandler delegateEmOutroLugar = delegate(string url) {
    /* Faço alguma coisa aqui, como uma função. */
};

var meuServidor = new MeuServidor();
// Posso definir agora minha função de delegate, assim:
meuServidor.minhaFuncaoDelegate = delegateEmOutroLugar;
// E executar assim:
meuServidor.minhaFuncaoDelegate("http://umsitequalquer");
```

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo com e sem delegate?

Comment: @RowAraujo Atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 11):

A grosso modo é uma forma de guardar um código em uma variável. Ou seja, de uma certa forma simplificadamente falando, o valor da variável é um código que poderá ser invocado em algum momento.

## Quando usar

A ideia geral indica o uso sempre que quiser permitir que uma ação possa ser configurada a posteriori.

Um exemplo de uso da ideia geral é o LINQ. Ele sabe executar certas ações mas não sabe os detalhes específicos de como fazer isto, então ele espera que você passe um código para ele:

```
objeto.Where(x => x == 0);
```

Dentro do `Where()` é feito uma série de coisas. Em determinado momento ele precisa decidir se deve pegar um dado ou não. Esta decisão o `Where()` não sabe qual é, então ele recebe um código que define como fazer a comparação. Este código é o que está sendo passado aí como argumento do `Where()`. Lá dentro isto será executado como se fosse um método, e o resultado é que será usado. Note que este código não será executado aí. Ele será executado lá dentro no momento que ele for útil, quantas vezes forem necessárias. E em cada chamada será passado pelo código dentro do `Where()` um argumento, que será recebido por este código como o parâmetro `x`.

Isto é chamado de *callback function*, já que definimos uma função que será usada como "parâmetro" do que deve executar (chamar de volta).

Esta é uma forma de delegação, mas não da forma apresentada na pergunta.

Em eventos é outra grande utilização, afinal o evento sempre precisa chamar um determinado método que ele não sabe exatamente o que faz. Ele só sabe como é o contrato deste deste método. É algo externo ao conhecimento dele. Um outro trecho de código dirá qual é a real implementação.

[*Delegate*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) na forma apresentada na pegunta praticamente não deve ser usado. Esta forma era necessária no início do C# e ainda é necessária em casos bem específicos, em geral, para criar uma abstração melhor.

## Seu funcionamento

Quando criamos um delegado estamos dizendo ao código que vamos ter ali algo que precisa ser executado, mas ainda não sabemos exatamente o que, só sabemos como deverá ser feita a chamada.

A forma apresentada é apenas a **declaração** do delegado. Como o próprio nome diz é uma forma de delegar uma ação para um código que ainda será estabelecido. A declaração consta apenas da [assinatura do método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) esperado. Isto é importante para o compilador saber como tratar aquele delegado específico, e gera um novo tipo na aplicação.

Assim, toda vez que uma variável for criada usando este tipo ele saberá como invocar o método de forma adequada de acordo com a assinatura fornecida. A variável irá armazenar uma referência para um método concreto criado em algum momento no desenvolvimento da aplicação. Quando atribuímos um código à variável que será a delegada estamos **definindo** seu valor. Ou seja, estamos apontando um comportamento específico que valerá até que outro código mude o apontamento.

No momento que fazemos uma chamada de método através desta variável delegada, estamos **executando** o código que está apontado por ela.

Quando criamos esta forma de delegação estamos dizendo ao código que sabemos que um determinado método precisa existir ali, e sabemos qual é sua assinatura. Só não sabemos ainda qual é seu corpo, o que realmente ele faz na implementação concreta. Alguma outra parte do código dirá o que deve fazer. E é possível mudar o que deve ser executado a qualquer momento em tempo de execução.

## Terminologia

Se conhece outras linguagens isto é o mesmo que um *function pointer*. O delegado é uma das formas de ter um ponteiro para uma função. Existem outros [termos sinônimos ou relacionados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101).

## Forma mais moderna

Hoje, em C#, usamos mais a [*lambda*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), que é uma função anônima com uma sintaxe mais simples e que, em geral, dispensa a declaração do delegado.

Isto não quer dizer que ele não exista, apenas que não é preciso escrevê-lo. O compilador infere a assinatura daquele método e cria o delegado para você. Em alguns casos onde a inferência não é possível, dá para usar um [`Func`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) ou [`Action`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) para substituir a declaração do delegado.

## Formas de definir o código

Claro que o método ou código solto deve existir e ser previamente compilado (até é possível fazer essa compilação em tempo de execução, mas isto é menos comum e só recentemente ficou mais fácil fazer isto). O método concreto que deve ser usado pode ser definido do jeito tradicional ou pela sintaxe de *lambda* ou de *delegate* (note que a palavra-chave `delegate` é usada para declarar um delegado e também para definir um, mas ambos são incomuns hoje, já que o uso de *lambda* é mais conveniente*).

Você pode usar qualquer método existente na aplicação, incluindo métodos existentes no .NET como implementação concreta de um delegado. Claro, desde que a assinatura bata com a declarada no delegado. Há métodos que possuem um membro escondido que é o tal do `this`, então pode parecer que um método tem uma mesma assinatura e na verdade ser outra.

Então seu exemplo poderia ser definido assim:

```
public static void Metodo(string url) => WriteLine(url); // só um exemplo
```

E definiria o delegado assim:

```
HTTPRequestsHandler handler = Metodo; //é o método acima
```

Ou pode simplificar um pouco e fazer a definição do método e do delegado ao mesmo tempo:

```
HTTPRequestsHandler handler = delegate(string url) {
    WriteLine(url); // só um exemplo
};
```

Ou como *lambda* (`HTTPRequestsHandler`  nem precisa existir):

```
var handler = (string url) => WriteLine(url); // só um exemplo
```

## Comparando com interfaces

Conhece bem o uso de [interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101) ou [classes abstratas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87489/101)? Uma interface se assemelha muito com um delegado, só que a interface concretiza o método de forma fixa e definida em tempo de compilação. O delegado pode ser definido em tempo de execução (ainda que o código em si a ser executado também será definido em tempo de compilação).

```
interface IManipulador {
    public void HTTPRequestsHandler(string url);
}

class Exemplo : IManipulador {
     public void HTTPRequestsHandler(string url) => WriteLine(url); // só um exemplo
}
```

Fez a mesma coisa. Qualquer classe que implemente a interface `Manipulador` pode ter um método que é garantido que atende as necessidades (a assinatura) imposta no delegado. Só que não tem flexibilidade de trocar em tempo de execução.

```
public delegate void HTTPRequestsHandler(string url);

class Exemplo {
     public HTTPRequestsHandler handler = (string url) => WriteLine(url); // só um exemplo
}
```

Aí você pode fazer:

```
var x = new Exemplo();
x.handler("http://dominio.br/pagina.html"); //escreve isto pulando uma linha
x.handler = (string url) => Write(url);
x.handler("http://dominio.br/pagina.html"); //escreve isto sem pular a linha
```

Pronto, mudou o que deve fazer de fato, agora imprime sem pular linha. O exemplo é bobo mas mostra a flexibilidade. O consumidor desta classe pode dizer como deve ser o manipulador. Claro que se não tomar cuidado pode abusar disto.

Esta é uma forma de evitar herança e polimorfismo e várias situações (ainda que isto seja uma forma de polimorfismo). Não quer dizer que deva em todos, claro, tudo tem o momento certo para usar.

Esta classe poderia ser escrita da forma mais moderna evitando a declaração do delegado:

```
class Exemplo {
     public Action<string> handler = (string url) => WriteLine(url); // só um exemplo
}
```

Neste caso específico, já que [`WriteLine()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Console_Write_System_String_) possui uma assinatura compatível, pode fazer melhor ainda:

```
class Exemplo {
     public Action<string> handler = WriteLine; // só um exemplo
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UbfkKq). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XjSJZA). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/Delegate.cs).

## Mais informações

Poderia falar dos [delegados *multicast*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/how-to-combine-delegates-multicast-delegates?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e seu uso principalmente com [eventos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Mas é melhor entender uma parte de cada vez.

[Artigo bem interessante sobre o assunto](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx).