# Delegate vazio ( delegate { } )

Tags: c#, .net, delegate

O que retorna a instrução `delegate { }`? Seria um delegado vazio?

Em que situações seria necessário criar um delegado vazio?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O que é um `delegate`?

Grosso modo é um ponteiro para um método, certo? Então o que terá nele é um endereço para algo que pode ser executado. Isso pode ser guardado em variáveis. E esta é a grande vantagem do `delegate`, você pode **variar** o que será executado, já que aquela variável pode apontar em um momento para uma função, em outro momento para outra função.

Quando você precisa inicializar o `delegate` e

- não quer ainda dar uma função útil para ele e deixar isto para mais tarde,
- ou quer que a função seja "fazer nada",

então podemos atribuir ao delegado uma função vazia, ou seja, que executa nada.

Então a função é vazia, o delegado não, porque ele é o ponteiro. Um delegado vazio na verdade seria um nulo.

Referências adicionais:

- [Delegates e métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116095/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre event e delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56957/101)
- [Quando e onde usar um delegate no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101238/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

Só para complementar a resposta do @Maniero, aonde é usado...  eu particularmente uso para iniciar eventos para não me preocupar se o evento é `null`

Por exemplo:

```
public class Teste{

  public event EventHandler MeuEvento;
  public event EventHandler MeuEvento2 = delegate { };

  public void MetodoExemplo(){

      //se quiser disparar o evento deve-se antes checar se alguem se registrou, 
     if (MeuEvento != null)
         MeuEvento(null,null);

     //agora como iniciamos o event não precisamos se "preocupar"
     MeuEvento2 (null,null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Com C# 6 pode-se também escrever algo do tipo `MeuEvento?.Invoke(null,null)`